# prove ratio between hypervolume and surface volume of n-sphere is optimal

Tags: geometry, surfaces, volume

The ratio of the surface volume to hypervolume of an $n$-sphere is $\frac{r}{(n+1)}$ . Is there a way to prove that this is the highest ratio possible without appealing to the fact that $n$-spheres maximize this quantity?

This falls right out of the volume and surface area formulas

$$ V_n(r) = \frac{\pi^{n/2}r^n}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2} + 1)} $$

dividing $V_n$ by its derivative with respect to $r$ gives us $n+1$, or the dimension of the space we're embedding the sphere in.

For an arbitrary non-self-intersecting $n$-manifold enclosing finite volume in $\mathbb{R}^{(n+1)}$ , the definition of the surface area and volume are straightforward. The radius is a little bit tricker, but I think it makes sense to use $\frac{d}{2}$ with $d$ being the maximum distance between any two points on the surface. This notional radius is only there to "normalize" the ratio based on the size of the shape in a way that keeps the resulting expression friendly.

Is there a way of proving that the maximum attainable value for $\frac{V_n}{\text{SA}\cdot r}$ is $\frac{1}{n+1}$ without first demonstrating that the most efficient shape is an $n$-sphere?

Comment: I'm not too sure exactly what you are asking here. Are you looking for a proof of the [isoperimetric inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality)?

Comment: @EuYu , yes! Thanks. That’s way better than the weird construction I had with the half maximum distance between two points. I was wondering if there are ways of proving it without knowing the exact shape that achieves the optimal value. I’m curious about what happens with non-L2 norms, for instance.

Comment: The fact that the sphere is the optimal shape emerges from the proof. You don't need to "know" it beforehand if that's what you mean. You can certainly generalize the result to other measure metric spaces, and for different spaces you will have different shapes which saturate the inequality. The results will be very sensitive to how you define distance, volume, and area of course. A key term that might help you search for some relevant results is "isoperimetric profile".